# Annotation @SQLInsert - How to insert all fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping, sql-insert

There is an example of using `@SQLInsert`

```
@SQLInsert (Sql = "INSERT INTO CHAOS (size, name, nickname, id) VALUES (?, Upper (?),?,?)")
```

In my case, I have a table with many fields (more than 20). How do I write a query correctly, if I always insert all the fileds?

Answer (score 0):

To insert all the fields except primary key please use below SQL insert syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)
```

In your case,

```
INSERT INTO CHAOS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PostgreSQL, you can try

```
INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 'Cheese');
```

It fills the columns from the left with as many values as are given, and the rest will be defaulted.